# Need to get token from custom API on server through login

Tags: android, api

I was doing some coding to post my request on custom API which is on server and get a token in return which will help user to login. but the problem is that i am quite new in this and after searching throughout i coded. but i realized that i didn't use any function to get token from that server. I have used the default login activity of android studio 3.1. 
Here is my code of java.

```
AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
EditText mPasswordView;
String Email,Password;

private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;


private static final String[] CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
};

private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{

                GetText();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}

public void GetText() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{


    Email   = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    Password    = mPasswordView.getText().toString();



    String data = URLEncoder.encode("nEmailView", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("mPasswordView", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Password, "UTF-8");

    String text = "";
    BufferedReader reader=null;

    try
    {

        URL url = new URL("http://himalayanheat.com/api/login"); //api link

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;


        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        text = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            reader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }

}
private void populateAutoComplete() {
    if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
        return;
    }

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            populateAutoComplete();
        }
    }
}

private void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }


    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
           focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
          showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    return password.length() > 4;
}



private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
    };

    int ADDRESS = 0;
    int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
}


public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

         return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Kindly also can anyone guide me about CREDENTIALS. I am using Dummy Credentials.

Comment: For more information regarding the server, it is made in PHP laravel framework. And database used is MSSQL. I have done work with firebase but this system is also posing problem for me

Comment: sad that haven't got an answer yet as the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, There were many issues but the solution was first **Posting my request** on server then getting the **Token back through API**
To achieve that firstly i used empty activity to create my own system (not built in login activity) after that on button i created a onclick function which was basis of getting data

**Here is my Code:**

```
    public void signin_button(View v){
Email = email.getText().toString();
Password = password.getText().toString();
BackGround b = new BackGround();
b.execute(Email, Password);}
class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String email = params[0];
    String password = params[1];
    String data="";
    int tmp;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("Website link can't show");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(param));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
            data+= (char)tmp;
        }
        is.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        return data;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
    }
}
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> param) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (NameValuePair pair : param)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
} @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    String err=null;
    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
        Token = root.getString("token");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, LoginActivity2.class);
    i.putExtra("token", Token);
    i.putExtra("err", err);
    startActivity(i);
}}}
```

**Getting internet permission in manifest is also necessary**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**FYI While testing on mobile kindly turn internet connection on (this reason cost me 2 days).**